# Apache disable DNS lookups

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.2

I'm using Debian 4.3.2-1 and Apache 2 on my production server. Watching the logs, I noticed Apache is resolving client's hostnames even with `HostnameLookups Off` in `apache2.conf`. I want to avoid these lookups so I'm guessing Apache is making this DNS query because I have `mod_authz_host` enabled. When I try to unlink this module, I get several modules complaining because they use the `Order` directive.

How is the clean way to go? Should I comment all Order directives like

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```

Is this the only way to stop Apache from making DNS requests? I would like to deny access to `.htaccess` files and some rules like that.

Answer (score 1):

`mod_authz_host` will only perform DNS lookups, if you actually use domain names in any Allow/Deny directive (and then this will happen irrespective of the HostnameLookups setting). So if you don't want those DNS lookups happening, get rid of the domain-name based authorisation config, if that's at all possible.

Comment: Does 'Allow from localhost' perform a lookup? I have only 'All', 'None' and localhost names in my directives.

Thank you very much for your help. it's nice i can keep the module working.

Comment: Most likely, yes, but this lookup won't be costly (assuming you have an entry for localhost in `/etc/hosts`). But if that bothers you, better use `Allow from 127.0.0.1` instead (also add `::1` if you have IPv6 enabled).

Comment: thank you earl, i think my problem was LogFormat using %h, which to my surprise forces a dns lookup ignoring HostNameLookup.

Wonder why debian's apache 2 has %h on default config when it's rarely needed...  

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined

i found it here http://betabug.ch/blogs/ch-athens/933

Comment: I doubt that's really the problem. `%h` is in Apache's default LogFormat alongside HostnameLookups switched off. I also use `%h` on many of my hosts with hostname lookups turned off (mostly Apache 2.2.9 on Debian Lenny), and don't see any resolved IPs in my logfiles. But if using a different LogFormat fixes things for you, it's great.